# C# Keyboard button used to trigger a method

Tags: c#, keyboard-events

I'm writing a Hangman program in C# and when I press a keyboard button I want the button on the form to be clicked. Where should I write this? In form1.load()?

Comment: If you find that our answers don't respond to your question, please edit your question with more info so we can elaborate some more. If you have your answer already, please let us know what is the correct answer by marking it as such, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, you should select the **Form** on which you want the event to be triggered, then go to the *properties pane*, select the *event tab* and go down to *KeyPress event*, double click it and add some code.

Normaly something like this would do what you want, just google the KeyChar value to determine the keyPress you want to control, you can add more if statements:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        {
            Button1.PerformClick();
        }

    //Other if statements if you want to keep an eye out for other keyPresses
}
```

[edit] I just remembered you might be also considering the shortcuts, in wich case the `Button1.Text` property should be marked `&Button1`, this way the "B" would be underlined and accept the `alt+B` shortcut to execute the button click event. 
The **&** symbol is set before the letter you want for the shortcut, make sure you dont use the same letter for various buttons.

Comment: Don't forget to set the form's property KeyPreview to true.
Check it out here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: @GorgiRankovski I just tested with `KeyPreview = false;` and it worked. I understand what you're saying and it seems logical, but i have no justification for you, as to why it works, even with that property as false. Any ideas?

Comment: About my previous comment, i thought a bit about what i tested (empty form) and tested the same thing with some controls in it. So if i set `KeyPreview = false;` i will be able to interact with the controls without firing the KeyPress event, so you do need to activate the KeyPreview property. But when `KeyPreview = true;` it will fire the KeyPress event whenever i press the key, so i would suggest some control over what key is set to fire the actions (sugegsted if statements) or every hit on the keyboard will run those actions. That might be intended, but just so you know what'll happen.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't write the code in `Form.Load()` if you want it to happen in response to a *keyboard* event. That event occurs (and the code inside of it is executed) when your form first loads (appears on screen).

How about handling the [`KeyPress` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) and writing the code in that method, instead? Your form has one of those events, too.

Sample code:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    Button1.PerformClick();
}
```

The [`PerformClick` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx) will generate a `Click` event for a [`Button` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.aspx). You can handle that `Click` event in a similar way:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something in response to the button being clicked
    // ...

    MessageBox.Show("Button clicked!");
}
```

If this event-handling stuff is confusing to you, make sure that you pick up a good book on programming in C# and/or the .NET Framework so that you learn it well. It's very important and not something to skip!

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) property on the form, then you have to implements the [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event directly on the form :

```
Form1.KeyPress +=new KeyPressEventHandler(Form1_KeyPress);

private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
        if(e.KeyCode == someKey) {
button1.performclick();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
  {
    // Do your hang job
    Button_Click(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the events of interest and process them after. But before you need to read and study how to do that. It's a not a difficult issue in C#.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171534.aspx

One time subscribed to the events create a function that you can call from button click and from keydown.